# How are relativistic tidal forces different from their Newtonian counterparts?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, tidal-effect

Conceptually, the tidal effects of Newtonian gravity differ drastically from that of general relativity. In Newtonian gravity, the effect is due to the change in gravitational force across a certain distance, while in general relativity it corresponds to geodesic deviation and is a result of curvature.

However, from how I see it, they are not very different mathematically.

The Newtonian tidal equation is derived by making a Taylor expansion of the gravitational field.

$$a\approx 2 \Delta r ~G\frac{M}{r^3}$$

The relativistic one uses the geodesic deviation equation and the Riemann curvature tensor for the Schwarzschild metric.

$$a = \Delta r ~\frac{r_s}{r^3}\approx 2 \Delta r ~G\frac{M}{r^3}$$

They both seem to give the same result, even in regions that relativistic descriptions should seem to dominate, like near a black hole. For example, the calculation of the Roche limit of a black hole seems to be identical to that of a more Newtonian object like a star.

Am I missing something here? Am I being too liberal with the "$\approx$" sign? Perhaps there are regimes in which relativistic tidal effects are dramatically different from Newtonian? Or do they differ only conceptually, but in fact produce the same numbers?

Comment: Firstly, could you elaborate on how our questions are the same? Mine has nothing to do with micro black holes Secondly, was my comment inaccurate? I simply quoted the article you linked.

Answer (score 1):

In the weak-field limit, GR and Newton give the same result. You have only shown the radial component of the tidal tensor:

$$ E_{\hat r\hat r} = -\frac{2M}{r^3} $$

There are also two angular components:

$$E_{\hat{\theta}\hat{\theta}} =E_{\hat{\phi}\hat{\phi}}=+\frac{M}{r^3}$$

which induces a volume-preserving squishing along with the radial stretching. Volume is preserved because the tidal tensor is traceless:

$$ E_{ij} = J_{ij}-\frac 1 3 J_{kk} $$

with

$$ J_{ij} = \frac {d^2U}{dx^i dx^j}$$

being the Hessian of the potential $U(r)$.

In GR, one starts with the Weyl curvature tensor, $C_{\mu\nu\sigma\lambda}$. The Newtonian tidal force along a geodesic is reproduced by

$$E_{\mu\nu} = u^{\sigma}u^{\lambda}C_{\mu\sigma\nu\lambda}$$

which is called the gravioelectric tensor.

The frame-dragging (and velocity dependent) part, unique to GR, is described by the graviomagnetic tensor:

$$H_{\mu\nu} = \frac 1 2 u^{\sigma}u^{\lambda}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\sigma(\mu}C^{\alpha\beta}_{\ \ \,\,\,\nu)\lambda}$$

While $E_{\mu\nu}$ leads to differential stretching and squishing, $H_{\mu\nu}$ leads to differential twisting (frame-dragging).

Such things are hard to visualize, so the integral curves of the eigenvectors of these tensors are used. They are called tendex lines and vortex lines, respectively (see figure).

[image]

Comment: Does the gravioelectric tensor agree with the Newtonian tidal tensor even outside the weak field limit? In other words, is the graviomagnetic tensor the only new effect introduced by GR?